# Менять value кнопки при вводе данных в текстовое поле

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть поле ввода в форме и кнопка — обычный *input submit*.

Требуется, чтобы когда поле пустое, на кнопке была одна надпись, а как только начали вводить данные - изменилась на другую. А если данные стереть из поля - тут же должна появиться первая надпись на кнопке, когда данных еще не было.

Вопрос сводится просто к тому, как примерно построить алгоритм и что именно лучше использовать. Пробовал `change` и `keypress` *JQuery*, но немного не то получается.

Comment: А что не так с keypress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
<input type="text" name="" class="inp">
<input type="submit" value="I'm button" class="btn">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('.inp').on('keyup', function(e) {
        var btnVal = ($(this).val()) ? "I'm changed button" : "I'm button";
        $('.btn').val(btnVal);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `keyup` не вызывается при использовании контекстного меню (например, `вырезать`). В новых браузерах лучше использовать `change`.

Comment: Сработало, огромное спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

Решение на чистом JS:

https://jsfiddle.net/11111000000/mtpfq5t9/2/

```
var 
  input = document.querySelector('input')
  , button = document.querySelector('button')
  , textOne = 'Введите что-нибудь'
  , textTwo = 'Спасибо';

input.addEventListener('keyup',function(event) {
    if(!this.value || this.value.trim() == '') {
      button.innerText = textOne; 
    } else {
      button.innerText = textTwo;    
    }
});
```

По-поводу оптимального пути решения подобных задач, смотрите в сторону двух-стороннего биндинга (two-way data binding).  Есть фреймворки, есть и микробиблиотеки.

Comment: `keyup` не вызывается при использовании контекстного меню (например, `вырезать` или `вставить`). В новых браузерах лучше использовать `change`.

Comment: А еще, `button.innerText` не работает, например, в firefox. Вы бы хотя бы предупредили, что ваше решение не кроссбраузерное.

Comment: Для решения проблем кроссбраузерности нужно задать другой вопрос. Моё решение - чистое, простое и верное, отражает суть вопроса.  Насчёт keyup вы уже отписали выше, это действительно верно, общеизвестно, но абсолютно никакого отношения не имеет к сути вопроса, вы просто как будто кичитесь граблями, на которые наступили )

Comment: Я и сказал, что вы стоило _хотя бы упомянуть_ о том что код не кроссбраузерный. А про `change`, так это событие даже в вопросе упоминается.

Comment: Большое спасибо за решение